# Can't find Blockchain data in API response

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm using the composer files of the [IoT Asset Tracking Perishable Goods Network project](https://github.com/johnwalicki/IoT-AssetTracking-Perishable-Network-Blockchain/tree/master/Blockchain/IoT-Perishable-Network).

**In Playground:** 
After initializing  (SetupDemo transaction) I ran the AccelReading transaction twice, which are reflected in the Shipment asset:

```
{ 
    "$class": "org.acme.shipping.perishable.Shipment", 
    "shipmentId": "320022000251363131363432", 
    <shipment data>, 
    "AccelReadings": [ 
        { 
            "$class": "org.acme.shipping.perishable.AccelReading", 
            <accelreading data 1>
            "timestamp": "2018-09-11T17:48:04.692Z"
        }, 
        { 
            "$class": "org.acme.shipping.perishable.AccelReading", 
            <accelreading data 2>
            "timestamp": "2018-09-11T18:59:27.340Z"
        } 
    ] 
}
```

The problem is, I can't see the **accelreading data x** when using the **Composer REST API**:

- The AccelReading API response contains $class, shipment, transactionId,
  timestamp.
- The Shipment API response contains $class, shipmentId, shipment data.

Comment: if you do a `/GET` by ID on the REST API endpoint `Shipment` (specifically by ID 320022000251363131363432) you should see the AccelReading inputs that you showed above in playground..... If you're looking at 'other Shipments' in /GET Shipment (all shipments) - you need remember that the model defines  AccelReadings as `AccelReadings optional` - so they may not have any readings.

Comment: The /GET by ID (/AccelReading/AccelReading_findById) response is identical ($class, shipment, transactionId, timestamp), but only reading

Comment: hi there, I mentioned the Shipment REST API. You wil only see the AccelReadings data (as per the transaction you posted) in the asset (Shipment), not the Transaction GET REST API endpoint AccelReadings (the response for that in the REST API  is 'what comes back from the blockchain' ie transaction info for the class submitted).

Comment: have just reviews the business network model: for the Shipment API (Get by ID), try adding the following in the filter field  `{"include":"resolve"}` to get it to resolve the array of transaction objects.

Comment: that works, thx

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Paul I'm using a different API and a filter field.